# None of Index are in the columns - Cannot do an single line boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Until now:

1. I load a csv file, without header. I put in new column names.
2. I strip away all spaces
3. I organize the data. All *R150* appear.
   But I cant do a Boxplot of my *Istwert* Column. Error:

   "None of [Index([',Istwert'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

If I save the csv, I do not find any suspicious.

Any ideas?

The code so far:

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("<FILELOCATION>", delimiter=";" , skiprows = 1, names=["BID","Testschritt","Testbeschreibung","Sollwert","Minimum","Maximum","Istwert","Einheit"])
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if (x.dtype == "object") | (x.dtype == "float") else x)
    result = df.loc[df["Testschritt"] == "R150"]
    result.boxplot(column = ["Istwert"])
```

This is my CSV data:
[image: Picture of csv]

And this is my result before the boxplot:
[image: Result of data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always provide your data as text,  not an image.  OCR is painful.

This works for me.

1. what version of pandas are you using?
2. what are your data types?

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
{'idx': [226, 1070, 1914, 2758, 3602, 4446, 5290, 6134, 6978, 7822],
 'BID': [7249, 7326, 7327, 7328, 7329, 7330, 7331, 7332, 7333, 7333],
 'Testschritt': ['R150','R150',  'R150',  'R150',  'R150',  'R150',  'R150',  'R150',  'R150',  'R150'],
 'Testbeschreibung': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'Sollwert': [22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22],
 'Minimum': [19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8, 19.8],
 'Maximum': [24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2],
 'Istwert': [20953,  21002,  20838,  20827,  20879,  20942,  20999,  20855,  20969,  20874],
 'Einheit': ['KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm',  'KOhm']}
).set_index("idx")
print(f"pandas: {pd.__version__}\n{result.dtypes}")
result.boxplot(column = ["Istwert"])
```

**output**

```
pandas: 1.1.0
BID                   int64
Testschritt          object
Testbeschreibung      int64
Sollwert              int64
Minimum             float64
Maximum             float64
Istwert               int64
Einheit              object
dtype: object
```

[image]

Comment: My Panda Version ist now 1.1.0.
My Datatypes are Object, instead of "BID". I cannot cast them?! 
obviously it retrives my data from excel to .csv as object, but is there a way to change it or to cast my data in another way? 

Kind regards,

Comment: use `astype()` to cast your data to appropriate data type.  pass it a dictionary of column names and required data type.  there maybe data that cannot be casted... that may mean you need some data clean up